# Strom Petrel AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: apache-storm

I'm trying Petrel with wordcount sample but find this problem:

> $petrel submit --config topology.yaml --logdir pwd
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.4.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 111, in main
>   func(**args.dict)
>   File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.4.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 32, in submit
>   sourcejar = get_sourcejar()
>   File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.4.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 23, in get_sourcejar
>   storm_version = get_storm_version()
>   File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.4.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 19, in get_storm_version
>   return m.group(0)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I also try:
$./buildandrun --config topology.yaml
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages ~/wordcount

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/jonas/Downloads/Petrel-master/petrel/setup.py", line 66, in
>   build_petrel()
>   File "/home/jonas/Downloads/Petrel-master/petrel/setup.py", line 29, in build_petrel
>   version_string, version_number = get_storm_version()
>   File "/home/jonas/Downloads/Petrel-master/petrel/setup.py", line 21, in get_storm_version
>   return m.group(0), m.group(1)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>   Error on or near line 20; exiting with status 1

I'd tried with virtualenv:

> $source petrel/bin/activate
>   and without
>   $easy_install --install-dir /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages petrel==0.9.4.0.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    @classmethod
    def declareOutputFields(cls):
    return ['study_id', 'segment_id', 'user_id', 'date_stamp',
            'time_stamp', 'x', 'start_date',
            'start_time', 'users', 'everyone']
```

Always check you emit/return fields and class.